# What is TEMP in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I was playing Skyrim today, and I turned off collision (tcl) so I could fly trough walls.  I was in Saarthal Excavation, and OUTSIDE OF THE WALL,there was a stone, with the drawings you find in giant camps, but they were glowing.  I got closer to it, and it said "Activate TEMP".  I tried to activate it, but nothing happened.

Anyone know what this could be?

Answer (score 4):

It's simply the (player-visible) "display name" of the activator. It could literally be *any* text without changing what the stone does.

It's very likely that the stone is a left-over from the development time, (originally) with some code on it helping with debugging the area or quests running in it. You'll know for sure when you open the level in the Creation Kit, locate the activator, then check which script is bound to it.

For more infos about activators, see this article on the Creation Kit wiki: http://www.creationkit.com/Activator

Comment: If we're talking about the same thing, then [I don't see any scripts on it](https://i.imgur.com/q58QakS.png). (Or I'm missing something)

Comment: @WhynoTalos It could be a blank... Couldn't it?

Comment: @FinnRayment There are no scripts at all bound to it. I've checked and double-checked with the CK. I think someone needs to go and find all unused items in Skyrim and remove them.

Comment: Ok, I was just clarifying that blanks exist. Maybe the devs got carried away and forgot about it?

Comment: Just to clarify: If you remove a script (because it was a dev-testing script only anyway), it also gets removed from any activator (... or any other object) using it, which leaves the object behind nonetheless, just like you see in this example. To know for sure what happened, you'd have to hunt down and ask the level designer though.